# Can anybody tell me who this Pokemon is?

Tags: pokemon-go, pokemon-series

I’ve been looking everywhere for it online and I can’t  figure out who it might be. Thanks![image]

Comment: Comments were deleted. If you believe the question is poorly researched, please show that with a downvote rather than a comment. Similarly, if you believe the question is valid, please show that with an upvote.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure the title should have been "***Who's that Pokémon?!***"

Comment: @Valorum ***"IT'S PIKACHUUUUU!"***

Answer (score 66):

This Pokémon is Xatu from the Johto region, it is the evolution of Natu.

[image: Xatu image in Pokémon GO]

Xatu is a Psychic/Flying type Pokémon. It is number 178 in the Pokédex and described in Pokémon GO as:

> *MYSTIC POKEMON* 
>   *Xatu stands rooted and still in one spot all day long. People believe that this Pokémon does so out of fear of the terrible things it has foreseen in the future.*

More details can be found at the [Pokémon Go Wiki](https://pokemongo.fandom.com/wiki/Xatu).

Comment: Obligatory [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Xatu_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Pok.C3.A9mon_GO) link